# How to dismiss a MaterialAlertDialog when a hyperlink is clicked?

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-alertdialog, dismiss

Is there a way to dismiss/cancel a MaterialAlertDialog when a hyperlink inside the message was clicked?
Currently the browser is open and when you returned to the app the dialog is still open.
For the buttons there is a listener where you can dismiss/cancel the dialog.

What I want to achieve is to close the dialog when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

1. add onClickListener to TextView containing hyperlink
2. use onResume() method to close dialog after you return to it

Answer (score 0):

After reading a bit about setLinkMovementMethod I thought about somethink like:

```
textView.setLinkMovementMethod(new TextViewLinkHandler() {
   // do my stuff ... 
   // if left blank, nothing will happen on click at the link, so leave it blank to do nothing
})
```

With the mentioned TextViewLinkHandler()

```
public abstract class TextViewLinkHandler extends LinkMovementMethod {
  // add a method to handle the click
  // extract the url and open it
  // then dismiss the dialog
}
```

But maybe this is not the right approach.
What did you think?